# Why am I getting a JSONDecodeError while downloading data from Yahoo finance module

Tags: yahoo-finance

I am new to Python and I wrote a simple piece of code to download historical data for a given ticker symbol from **yfinance** module. The code was running for several weeks and recently, it started to throw the following exceptions. Here is the code:

```
data = yf.download("ibm", start="1/1/2017", end="1/6/2021")
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\PythonLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\multitasking\__init__.py", line 102, in _run_via_pool
    return callee(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\PythonLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 167, in _download_one_threaded
    data = _download_one(ticker, start, end, auto_adjust, back_adjust,
  File "C:\Python\PythonLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 179, in _download_one
    return Ticker(ticker).history(period=period, interval=interval,
  File "C:\Python\PythonLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", line 157, in history
    data = data.json()
  File "C:\Python\PythonLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not tech support. This question should be addressed to the authors or maintainers of `yfinance`, perhaps via a bug tracker.

Comment: Classic: the lib did not check the response code before reading the JSON.

Comment: I am not sure why this post is closed. This post is about a program call to a library that is not working as expected. Isn't stackoverflow a platform to solve programming problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that is fixed in the latest version of the `yfinance` module (0.1.63), per the GitHub repository's [Issue #777](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/777).

Update your `yfinance` module to 0.1.63 or later.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I have already installed the current version of Yfinance (0.1.63) using "pip install yfinance" but the error persists. Do I need to do anything beyond the pip install?

Comment: Per [#764](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/764), `pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks everything is working now but I am not sure why they closed the question.